# tkz, tikz-grph, tikzexternalize and pythontex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikz-graphs, pythontex

my code looks like that:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[]

\begin{pycode}
def gen_pop(arg_str):
    pop = list(arg_str)
    print('\\begin{{matrix}}& & {0} & &\\\\{1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5}\\end{{matrix}}'.format(pop[5], pop[0], pop[1], pop[2], pop[3], pop[4]))
\end{pycode}

\newcommand{\pop}[1]{
    \pyc{gen_pop('#1')}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1,xscale=1]
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
        \SetGraphUnit{2}
        \Vertex[L=$\pop{100000}$]{100000}
        \EA[L=$\pop{010000}$](100000){010000}
        \EA[L=$\pop{000001}$](010000){000001}
        \EA[L=$\pop{001000}$](000001){001000}
        \EA[L=$\pop{000100}$](001000){000100}
        \EA[L=$\pop{000010}$](000100){000010}

        \Vertex[L=$\pop{110000}$,a=-63.43,d=2.23]{110000}
        \EA[L=$\pop{011000}$](110000){011000}
        \EA[L=$\pop{001001}$](011000){001001}
        \EA[L=$\pop{001100}$](001001){001100}
        \EA[L=$\pop{000110}$](001100){000110}

        % ....

        \Edges(100000,110000)\Edges(010000,110000)\Edges(010000,011000)\Edges(001000,011000)
        \Edges(000100,001100)\Edges(001000,001001)\Edges(000001,001001)\Edges(000100,000110)
        \Edges(000010,000110)

        % ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I shorted it a little but it should produce something non-trivial. My build commands are in order (pythontex needs two runs):

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex" ?ame" -parse-first-line -shell-escape -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode; 
"c:\program files\miktex 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py" ?ame"; 
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex" ?ame" -parse-first-line -shell-escape -enable-write18 -aux-directory="C:\tmp" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
```

The problem is `tikzexternalize` doesnt catch the changes that `pythontex` is making. It is not showing the node labels (i.e. the matricies that are generated by the python code) so its only displaying the edges in the externalized pdfs. Is it possible to get this externalized with pythontex?

Another problem arises if I try to workaround the problem above by replace the `\pop{}` macro with the correct LaTeX code like so:

```
% ...
%1
\Vertex[L=$\begin{matrix}&&0&&\\1&0&0&0&0\end{matrix}$]{100000}
\EA[L=$\begin{matrix}&&0&&\\0&1&0&0&0\end{matrix}$](100000){010000}
\EA[L=$\begin{matrix}&&1&&\\0&0&0&0&0\end{matrix}$](010000){000001}
\EA[L=$\begin{matrix}&&0&&\\0&0&1&0&0\end{matrix}$](000001){001000}
\EA[L=$\begin{matrix}&&0&&\\0&0&0&1&0\end{matrix}$](001000){000100}
\EA[L=$\begin{matrix}&&0&&\\0&0&0&0&1\end{matrix}$](000100){000010}
% ...
```

Then it is complaining that the

```
Use of \tikz@@scope@env doesn't match its definition. ...rix}&&0&&\\1&0&0&0&0\end{matrix}$]{100000}
```

Without externalization everything works as expected. Except that generating a whole line like `\EA[L=$\pop{001001}$](011000){001001}` with python also ends in the error above. It seems like pythontex is encapsulating the matrix code so well that tikz can handle it. But its not working out if one types it there directly.

Anyway, I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to get `pythontex` and `tikzexternalize` to cooperate given how they currently work.  It is probably best to avoid `tikzexternalize` unless absolutely necessary.

`pythontex` saves all code to an external file, processes the code, and then brings the output back in on the next compile.  It keeps track of which output goes with which command using a version of `\jobname` combined with counters.  `tikzexternalize` recompiles the document for each picture using a custom `\jobname` with everything but the current `tikzpicture` environment "disabled".  So the first problem is that `tikzexternalize` changes `\jobname`, which means that `pythontex` can't find anything.  That can be fixed with something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzifexternalizing{
  \def\pytx@jobname{\tikzexternalrealjob}
  \def\pytx@outdir{pythontex-files-\tikzexternalrealjob}
}{}
\makeatother
```

This should be after the `\tikzexternalize`.

That would allow `pythontex` to find output if there were any.  But now the problem is that `tikzexternalize` changes `tikzpicture` in such a way that its content is in a way "invisible" as far as the main document is concerned.  So the main document never actually processes the `\pyc` commands, and output is never generated.

To work around that problem, you would need to generate the entire `tikzpicture` within a `pycode` environment and then print it.  That should get you back to your `\tikz@@scope@env` error.  Since the default `pythontex` approach works without `tikzexternalize`, you could try to replicate it.  That would involve saving a detokenized version of `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}` in a macro, and then using `\scantokens` to retokenize it when it is used.  There may be other ways to do this; that's just what `pythontex` does, which seems to work.  The relevant part of `pythontex.sty` is the definition of `\pytx@SVMCR`.  Unfortunately, all of this would make things way more complicated than the case without `tikzexternalize`.